What function do I need to use to get the bottom most populated value in a data range in excel?
I'm creating a macro in excel to generate an email that gives specific info included in a  workbook.
I need to include the value in the bottom most populated cell in the range "E65:E78". The workbook has values entered below this range so I cannot reference to the bottom most values in the column.
What format and function would be required to display this value?
With OutMail
        .To = "Email 1 Here"
        .CC = "Email 2 Here"
        .Subject = Range("A5").Value & " Event"
        .Body = "Example Text," & vbNewLine & "Example Text " & Range("A5") & " scheduled for " & Range("E65:E78") & "." & vbNewLine _
        & vbNewLine & "Example Text" & vbNewLine  & "Thanks." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
        .Display
        End With

Tried this but I received a runtime error

Run-time error '1004':
Method 'Range' of object'_Global' failed


Does this answer your question? How to select last populated cell in table column

Option1:

Check if the last cell is empty. If it is, find the last non-empty cell above it.

With OutMail
    .To = "Email 1 Here"
    .CC = "Email 2 Here"
    .Subject = Range("A5").Value & " Event"
    Dim c As Range
    With Range("E65:E78")
        Set c = .Cells(.Cells.Count) ' last cell (E78)
        If Len(c.Value) = 0 Then  ' if the last cell is blank
            Set c = c.End(xlUp) ' get the first non-blank cell
        End If
    End With
    .Body = "Example Text," & vbNewLine & "Example Text " & Range("A5") & " scheduled for " & c.Value & "." & vbNewLine _
    & vbNewLine & "Example Text" & vbNewLine  & "Thanks." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
    .Display
End With


Option2:

Using Find to locate the last non-blank cell

Microsoft documentation:

Range.Find method (Excel)

With OutMail
    .To = "Email 1 Here"
    .CC = "Email 2 Here"
    .Subject = Range("A5").Value & " Event"
    Dim c As Range
    With Range("E65:E78")
        set c = .Find(What:="*", After:=.Cells(1), _
            Lookat:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
            MatchCase:=False)
    End With
    .Body = "Example Text," & vbNewLine & "Example Text " & Range("A5") & " scheduled for " & c.Value & "." & vbNewLine _
    & vbNewLine & "Example Text" & vbNewLine  & "Thanks." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
    .Display
End With


Thank you taller for helping me out!
I tried both methods but only the first method seemed to work for me. The second method caused an error i could not resolve, but the first method works beautifully. I'd upvote your solution but I lack the reputation to do so.
Many thanks!

What is the error number and text?
